# Why am I getting a 404 when trying to post a comment?

Tags: support, api

I'm dabbling around in [`/posts/{id}/comments/add`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment), and I'm trying this query:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/posts/144890/comments/add?site=meta.stackover‌​flow&key=ArbQthisismykeyjyecuJQ((&access_token=2YVSaccesstokenomg))&body=and%20th‌​is%20is%20another%20test
```

It's giving me a 404:

```
{"error_name":"no_method","error_message":"this method cannot be called this way","error_id":404}
```

What am I doing wrong? I can perform the action just fine from the [doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment), but I can't from the API itself.

Comment: You need to `POST`, not `GET`.

Comment: Also related: http://stackapps.com/q/3897/21692

Comment: which **id** should i use there ? my user_id or question_id ? I get a an error called **Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write** @BrockAdams

Comment: could you see the comment in stackoverflow account @Undo

Comment: Not right now @Samson, traveling.

Comment: sure once your free @Undo lets continue this discussion in chat room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTTP GET

```
$.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/posts/144890/comments/add?site=meta.stackoverflow&key=ArbQjyecuJQ((&access_token=2YVSaccesstokenomg))&body=Another%20API%20test", console.log)
```

```
{"error_name": "no_method", "error_message": "this method cannot be called this way", "error_id": 404}
```

### HTTP POST

```
$.post("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/posts/144890/comments/add?site=meta.stackoverflow&key=ArbQjyecuJQ((&access_token=2YVSaccesstokenomg))&body=Another%20API%20test", console.log)
```

```
{"error_name": "bad_parameter", "error_message": "`key` doesn't match a known application", "error_id": 400}.
```

Ignoring the key error (presumably you put an invalid one in the post on purpose, and you have a real one stashed somewhere), Brock Adams' comment appears correct - this API path must be requested using a POST. Which makes a whole pile of sense, as GETs are defined as safe and idempotent operations, while POSTs are neither; and the adding of a comment is neither.

> ## [URIs, Addressability, and the use of HTTP GET and POST](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html)
>
> ### [§3](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#safe)
>
> In [section 9.1.1], HTTP/1.1 states, the convention is that `GET` is used for safe interactions and **SHOULD NOT** have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. Indeed, if you use `GET` for interactions with side-effects, your make your system insecure. For example, a malicious Web page publisher outside a firewall might put a URI in an HTML page so that, when someone inside the firewall unwittingly follows the link, that person activates a function on another system within the firewall.
>
> Users accept obligations through other mechanisms than requests to follow a link. Per the HTTP/1.1 specification, designers should use HTTP `POST` for those interactions.

> ## [RFC 2616: HTTP/1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)
>
> ### §9.1.1
>
> ...In particular, the convention has been established that the `GET` and `HEAD` methods **SHOULD NOT** have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe"...
>
> ### §9.1.2
>
> Methods can also have the property of "idempotence" in that (aside from error or expiration issues) the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request.

The only real problem here is that this is not mentioned anywhere in the Stack Exchange API documentation; [I've opened a bug report](https://stackapps.com/q/4463/21692).

Comment: So are we supposed to be using JsonP in order to call methods that require posts, since our apps aren't on the same domain? I'm having the same issue trying to add/remove favorites. I could swear it worked once on a get request, but it's not working now.