# Tell us that POST is required to write

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, documentation, write-access

While troubleshooting [`/posts/{id}/comments/add`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment) in order to answer [Why am I getting a 404 when trying to post a comment?](https://stackapps.com/q/4461/21692), it was noticed that the API path in question only responded to POST requests. This is all well and good, especially given that adding a comment is neither idempotent nor safe, which GETs should be (HTTP spec says so). However, there is just one problem:

***Nowhere in the documentation is it mentioned that you need to use POST to successfully write.***

Knowledge of the HTTP spec (and super deductive skills) told me and commenter Brock Adams the correct remedy (["*You need to `POST`, not `GET`.*"](https://stackapps.com/questions/4461/why-am-i-getting-a-404-when-trying-to-post-a-comment#comment10796_4461)), but I really think this should be documented.

Comment: As you know, I have additional [concerns about the documentation of the API](http://stackapps.com/questions/4577/incomplete-information-in-api-documentation)

Comment: it's 2017 now, and nothing changed.

Comment: And now it's 2018 and the documentation *still* doesn't mention it. SE: Seriously, how hard is it to change/add a small amount of text, so the people you're wanting to have make things which make you more money don't have to waste their time figuring this out? Admittedly, it was the one of the first possibilities that came to mind, based on the somewhat cryptic error message, but it wasn't the first thing I checked, because it wasn't mentioned in the documentation, and *surely* they'd state something so basic in the documentation.