# Incomplete information in API documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, api-v2.2, documentation

I am struggling a little bit with the Stack Exchange API since there seems to be no formal specification for the individual endpoints of the API.

### Example:

Endpoint: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/add`

Documentation Link: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question

On the screenshot you can see all the information I get for the endpoint. A few things weren't clear at first sight:

1. Is this a `POST` request or would `GET` also work?
2. What is the `Content-Type` (`x-www-form-urlencoded` or `json` ?)
3. Which fields are required which are optional
4. Description of all the fields:

   - What is `preview` for. What is the format: [true,false], ["true","false"], [0,1]?
   - How to format the list of tags?
   - What is the `key`, where to get it
   - How do responses look like (e.g. HTTP headers)
   - How would an example request look like

I did find out all of this information eventually but I had to make assumptions and do quite a bit of trial and error.

In contrast, the GitHub API for example has a different structure and provides most of the data at a glance. Example: [Create an GitHub Issue](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue)

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I know, right? [I've already reported the POST/GET issue](http://stackapps.com/q/4463/21692), but the rest of it's pretty bad too.

Comment: I just spent hours trying to figure out why I get a 400 status code. The problem was that the preview seems to be required....