# Syntax for Adding a Question as a Favorite?

Tags: support, api, write-access, favorite

I would like to be able to have my application make a request to the Stack Exchange API to favorite a question for the current user. The API specifies that this can be done via:

```
/2.2/questions/{id}/favorite
```

where id is the question ID.

However, I'm getting a 404 response whenever I call the following:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/11541695/favorite

The Documentation also mentions that I would have to use an `access_token`, but I'm not sure how to send it with it request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You cannot use a standard `GET` request.](https://stackapps.com/q/4463/7653)  You must obtain the `access_token` and then `POST` the necessary parameters.

The steps are currently:

**Setup:**

1. [Register your app.](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register)
2. Link it with [a post here on Stack Apps that has a legitimate [app] or [script] tag](https://stackapps.com/q/4573/7653).  In most cases you will also tag it with [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder).

**In your app:**

1. Have the user authorize your app and obtain an `access_token` by following the instructions in [the Authentication doc page.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)  Be sure to include `write_access` in the requested scope.

   Note that there are two different auth recipes: ***explicit*** and ***implicit***.
   Which one you are allowed to use is controlled by the ***Client Side Flow*** setting on [your app's registration page (visible only to you)](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/).

   If *Client Side Flow* is **Enabled** use the "**implicit**" recipe.
   Otherwise, use the "explicit" steps.

   For faster and easier code, **use [a library](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library?sort=votes&pageSize=50) or use [the JavaScript SDK](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib)** to handle authentication.
2. Send a `POST` to

   ```
   https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/{id}/favorite
   ```

   with the following parameters at a minimum:

   `id` =            {The question id -- same as in the POST URL}
   `key` =           {Your app's key}
   `site` =          stackoverflow   //-- Or whatever site you're operating on
   `preview` =       false
   `access_token` =  {The access token you obtained in step 1}
3. On success, the API will return JSON with [a question object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question). EG:

   ```
   {
     "items": [
     ... {question details} ...
     ],
     "has_more": false,
     "quota_max": 10000,
     "quota_remaining": 9996
   }
   ```