# Can I pass a filter to a write method?

Tags: support, api, filter, write-access

I was wondering if I'm allowed to pass a filter to methods that use write access? Like for example [`/answers/{id}/accept`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/accept-answer). There is no "filter" parameter, and changing the filter doesn't seem to change the URL, though "preview" doesn't do this too.

I'll vote for yes, but I don't have any API key or access token available, so I can't test this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**  You *can* pass a filter, and you *should* (for all [the standard reasons](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters)).

First: On the doc page, changing the filter or `preview`, etc. will not change the URL for write methods.
Write methods must `POST` to the API, which means that parameters are supposed to be sent form encoded, not in the URL.  (This API bakes some things, like post ID, into the route.  But, it is still not in the search/query/parameter part of the URL.)

---

Anyway, filters work with write methods.
For example, when **my own app** posts to:
          `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/7151/accept`

with **no filter** specified, it gets:

```js
items: [{
    owner: {
        reputation: 695,
        user_id: 42239,
        user_type: "registered",
        profile_image: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zweIW.png?s=128&g=1",
        display_name: "Bhargav Rao",
        link: "https://stackapps.com/users/42239/bhargav-rao"
    },
    is_accepted: true,
    score: 3,
    last_activity_date: 1485020864,
    last_edit_date: 1485020864,
    creation_date: 1482739375,
    answer_id: 7151,
    question_id: 7057
}],
has_more: false,
quota_max: 10000,
quota_remaining: 9994
```

-- which has a lot of properties that I don't care about.

But when I post **with a sensible filter** (`filter=!8IfkvFvN6wVk.*awhCzFz`), I get:

```js
items: [{
    owner: {
        display_name: "Bhargav Rao"
    },
    is_accepted: true,
    score: 3,
    answer_id: 7151
}],
has_more: false,
quota_max: 10000,
quota_remaining: 9993,
page: 1,
page_size: 30
```

---

---

Note that [that doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/accept-answer), like **most (¿all?) of the write-access doc pages, appears to be substantially broken.**  That is, I plug valid values into the inputs and get invalid (or no) results

Comment: Thanks! Is it documented somewhere that I have to POST for write methods?

Comment: Theoretically, [you are supposed to use `POST` any time you change anything via http(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/504993).  But you might want to go upvote [this bug report](https://stackapps.com/questions/4463/tell-us-that-post-is-required-to-write).